# How to redirect stderr to stdout in an Ant JUnit target?

Tags: ant, junit

I have a simple Ant build file to produce a JUnit test report in XML format (see below). This produces a report with each test method's output (if any) on stdout and stderr. I'd like the output on the two streams to be merged into one for each test method. But I'm not sure how to do this; how can I tell the JUnit target to redirect stderr to stdout?

```
<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <junit>
        <classpath refid="classpath.tests"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="tests.Tests1"/>
        <test name="tests.Tests2"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ant test | grep -w junit 2>&1
```

The Alternate option is : run Ant with q option.

```
ant -q test
```